# TabHost not showing layouts

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have used TabHost in my app. It is not showing the xml file on each tab click. Only white screen is shown. The classes and layouts are posted in question below. Please Help

```
public class HelpScreen extends TabActivity {

TabHost host;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inst_manual);

    host = getTabHost();

    TabSpec btnHelp = host.newTabSpec("Buttons Help");
    btnHelp.setIndicator("Buttons Help",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brushes_help));
    Intent buttonsHelp = new Intent().setClass(this, ButtonsHelp.class);
    btnHelp.setContent(buttonsHelp);

    TabSpec drawHelp = host.newTabSpec("Drawing Help");
    drawHelp.setIndicator("Drawing Help",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brushes_help));
    Intent drawingHelp = new Intent().setClass(this, DrawingHelp.class);
    drawHelp.setContent(drawingHelp);

    host.addTab(btnHelp);
    host.addTab(drawHelp);
}
}
```

Buttons Help Class is,

```
public class ButtonsHelp extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buttons_help); //THIS XML IS NOT SHOWN ON TAB CLICK
}
}
```

Help Screen Layout

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Post the layout of the `HelpScreen` activity. Also, you should rethink your approach, `TabActivity` has been deprecated for quite some time.

Comment: Edited the question. Kindly check it

Comment: Set the `orientation` of the `LinearLayout` with the id `tabLayout` to `vertical`. Right now the children of that `LinearLayout` are placed in a horizontal line, but as the `TabWidget` is set to fill the width the `FrameLayout` is pushed out of the screen.